# How to obtain the start and commit timestamps of transactions in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, transactions, timestamp, mongodb-oplog

### Motivation

We are working on a white-box checking algorithm of Snapshot Isolation (SI): given an execution of a database, to check whether it satisfies SI.

The SI checking problem is [NP-hard for general executions](https://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/%7Ecenea/papers/oopsla19.pdf).  So it is desirable to make use of the knowledge of how SI is actually implemented in databases.

The insight is that most databases, especially distributed databases, implement SI following a generic protocol using *start-timestamps* and *commit-timestamps*.  With these timestamps of transactions in an execution, the SI checking problem becomes solvable in polynomial time. Therefore, we want to obtain these timestamps when generating executions.

It is crucial for us to really understand the meaning of the start-timestamps and commit-timestamps in the database under testing. We must be very sure that we have obtained the right timestamps in the right way.

That is why we ask for help here.

### Background

We are digging into the implementation of snapshot isolation of MongoDB, especially into the use of timestamps in transactions.

Consider the classic description of *start-timestamp* and *commit-timestamp* in implementing Snapshot Isolation, quoted from the [paper; Section 4.2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/tr-95-51.pdf):

> ***For start-timestamp***: A transaction executing with Snapshot Isolation always reads data from a snapshot of the (committed) data as of the time the transaction started, called its *Start-Timestamp*. This time may be any time before the transaction’s first Read.

> ***For commit-timestamp***: When the transaction `T1` is ready to commit, it gets a *Commit-Timestamp*, which is larger than any existing Start-Timestamp or Commit-Timestamp.
> When `T1` commits, its changes become visible to all
> transactions whose Start-Timestamps are larger than `T1`'s Commit-Timestamp.

> ***For conflict detection***:
> The transaction `T1` successfully commits only if no other transaction `T2` with a Commit-Timestamp in `T1`'s execution interval [Start-Timestamp, Commit-Timestamp] wrote data that `T1` also wrote. Otherwise, `T1` will abort.  This feature, called First-committer-wins prevents lost updates.

### Our Problem

How can we obtain such *start-timestamp* and *commit-timestamp* of a transaction in MongoDB from, e.g., database logs?

### Our Solution

#### Environment

- MongoDB v7.0.2
- Python driver v4.1.1
- Sharded cluster deployment

  - [collections are assigned to different shards when created](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/)

  ```
  sh.shardCollection("<database>.<collection>", { <shard key field> : "hashed" } )
  ```

#### Run transactions in MongoDB

We use a simpler version of the [official example](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/core/transactions/#transactions-api) which uses the [`with_transaction`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/core/transactions-in-applications/#example) API.

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo.read_concern import ReadConcern
from pymongo.write_concern import WriteConcern

client = MongoClient(host="10.206.0.12", port=27017)

def callback(session):
    collection_one = session.client.mydb1.foo
    collection_one.insert_one({"abc": 1}, session=session)

with client.start_session() as session:
    session.with_transaction(
        callback,
        read_concern=ReadConcern("snapshot"),
        write_concern=WriteConcern("majority")
    )
```

#### To obtain the start-timestamp

According to [mongodb-setting-systemLog.verbosity @ docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-systemLog.verbosity), we provide the following configure file (`srs.conf`)

```yaml
sharding:
    clusterRole: shardsvr
replication:
    replSetName: rs2
net:
    bindIp: 0.0.0.0
storage:
  oplogMinRetentionHours: 48
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  component:
    transaction:
      verbosity: 1
```

when starting a mongod using the command

```
mongod --fork --logpath /root/mongo-config/mongo-srs.log --config srs.conf
```

The option `systemLog.component.transaction.verbosity` enables MongoDB to log the start-timestamp into the log file `/root/mongo-config/mongo-srs.log` which looks like:

```json
{
    ...
    "c":"TXN",
    "ctx":"conn80",
    "msg":"transaction",
    "attr":{
        "parameters":{
            "lsid":{
                "id":{
                    "$uuid":"d25844f9-b25b-4ed3-8734-cccf8a4c584a"
                },
                ...
            },
            "txnNumber":1,
            "readConcern":{
                "level":"snapshot",
                "atClusterTime":{
                    "$timestamp":{
                        "t":1696995553,
                        "i":2
                    }
                },
                "provenance":"clientSupplied"
            }
        },
        "readTimestamp":"Timestamp(1696995553, 2)",
        "terminationCause":"committed",
        ...
    }
}
```

`readTimestamp` (`Timestamp(1696995553, 2)`) is the start-timestamp of the transaction with `lsid` and `txnNumber`.

#### Question 1

- Have we obtained the start-timestamp correctly?
- Furthermore, what is the meaning of `atClusterTime` in the log above? Is it always the same with `readTimestamp` for multi-document transactions?

#### To obtain the commit-timestamp

The commit-timestamp of transactions are in the `oplog.rs` collection of the `local` database managed by MongoDB.

```json
{
    lsid: {
        id: new UUID("d25844f9-b25b-4ed3-8734-cccf8a4c584a"),
        uid: Binary(Buffer.from("e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855", "hex"), 0)
    },
    txnNumber: Long("1"),
    op: 'c',
    ns: 'admin.$cmd',
    o: {
        applyOps: [
            {
                op: 'i',
                ns: 'mydb1.foo',
                ui: new UUID("d9490802-b1bc-431d-90ac-db2a535ecc91"),
                o: { _id: ObjectId("652618e4b4c5bae6e2da451c"), abc: 1 },
                o2: { abc: 1, _id: ObjectId("652618e4b4c5bae6e2da451c") }
            }
        ]
    },
    ts: Timestamp({ t: 1696995556, i: 3 }),
    t: Long("15"),
    v: Long("2"),
    wall: ISODate("2023-10-11T03:39:16.566Z"),
    prevOpTime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 0, i: 0 }), t: Long("-1") }
}
```

`ts` (`Timestamp({ t: 1696995556, i: 3 })`) is the commit-timestamp of the transaction with `lsid` and `txnNumber`.

#### Question 2

- Have we obtained the commit-timestamp correctly?

### About Read-Only Transactions

We can obtain the start-timestamp of read-only transactions in the way as described above. We do *not* find commit-timestamp of read-only transactions in `oplog.rs`.

#### Question 3

Do read-only transactions have commit-timestamps in MongoDB? If so, how to obtain them?

### Thanks

Related: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-obtain-the-start-and-commit-timestamps-of-transactions-in-mongodb/248532?u=hengfeng_wei